# Read from one table and insert into another - one row at a time

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, .net

I am dealing with a huge database with millions of rows.  I would like to run an SQL statement through C#, which selects 1.2 million rows from one database, and inserts them into another after parsing and modifying some data.

I originally wanted to do so by first running the select statement and parsing the data by iterating through the `MySqlDataReader` object which contains the data.  This would be a memory overhead, so I have decided to select one row, parse it and insert into the other database, and then move onto the next row.

How can this be done? I have tried the `SELECT....INTO` syntax for a MySQL query, however this still seems to select all the data, and then inserts it after.

Answer (score 0):

Use SqlBulkCopy Class to move data from one source to other

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: But I need to do it one row at a time and parse each value to change them and modify.

Comment: can you provide a sample changes,whether it is summing two column or deleting value etc ?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you are able to add a new column to the existing table. If you are able to add a new column, you can use the new column as a flag. It could be "TRANSFERED(boolean)".

You will select one row at a time with the condition TRANSFERED=FALSE and do the process. After that row is processed, you should update as TRANSFERED=TRUE.

Or, you must have a uniqe id column in your existing table. Create a temp table which will store the id of processed rows, that way you will know which rows are processed or not

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure what is your error. For your case, I suggest you should use 'select top 1000 ' to get the data because insert row one by one is really slow. After that, you can use 'insert into query', it should be noted that sqlbulkcopy is just for sql server, I suggest you use the stringbuilder to make the sql query for if you use string, it will has a big overhead to concat the string.